# grouping textboxes together so that all of their properties can be changed with a simple loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 16 textboxes on my ASP.NET page, and I want to set their text values to equal the various values that are in my string array.

In my .ASPX file, I am defining the textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" />
```

This is how I've currently got it working in the code-behind:

```
this.textbox1.Text = stringArray[0];
this.textbox2.Text = stringArray[1];
...
this.textbox16.Text = stringArray[15];
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Textbox tb in GroupOfTextboxes)
{
 tb.Text = stringArray[i];
 i++;
}
```

What is the easiest way to set up the "GroupOfTextboxes"? I'd like to see code sample, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an array or `List` of `Textbox` objects:

```
Textbox[] textBoxes = new []{textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, ...};
```

another, possibly simpler, way of populating the data structure would be to put all of the textboxes into a `Panel` or other container of some sort.  Then you could do:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = myTextboxPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

That may or may not be a feasible option, but it is simpler.  It does require having some sort of container that all of the textboxes can go in that won't have any other textboxes.

After that you can use a `for` loop to do the copy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Lenth; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i].Text = stringArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Group them in a PlaceHolder like so:

```
<asp:placeholder id="plcHldrTextBoxes" runat="server">
    your text boxes here
</asp>
```

Now in C#, iterate through the controls in plcHldrTextBoxes:

```
int i=0;
foreach (var textBox in plcHldrTextBoxes.Controls)
{
   //dangerous if the cast fails but you get the idea
   (textBox as TextBox).Text = stringArray[i];
   i++; 
}
```

**In 2 lines using Linq (and safer than above):**

```
int i = 0;
place.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().AsParallel().ForAll(x => x.Text = stringArray[i++]);
```

Comment: Note that this is often a good solution, but sometimes it's not possible to put all of the needed controls into a container that has no other children of the same type, so it's not a magic bullet of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try naming all your textbox.id starting with "myTarget_" follow by something.
Then use LINQ to find the list of text box:

```
(From voTB As WebControl In Form.Controls Where left(voTB.ID,9) = "myTarget_" Select voTB)
```

Then you can do the loop thingy:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Textbox tb in (From voTB As WebControl In
Form.Controls Where left(voTB.ID,9) = "myTarget_" Select voTB)) { 
tb.Text = stringArray[i];  i++; }
```

You may need to tweak the code abit.

Answer (score 0):

a placeholder/panel/div seems like a suitable choice.  You could then ask for all the children of the placeholder.

another option would be to give them all meaningful and sequential names.. like say:  stringArrayTextbox1 .. stringArrayTextboxN

Then use FindControlByID to get your control.

I like the FindControlByID method best - it means that the order of the textboxes in the container control does not have to match the order of the array.